# Do we use 'competent' to indicate the person or body responsible for something?

Tags: word-usage

EU texts often refer to the 'competent body', 'competent department or 'competent official', meaning the body, department or official that is responsible for the activity in question. For example:

> Since more direct contacts between the authorities and officials of the Member States might be necessary for reasons of efficiency, the provisions on delegation and the designation of competent officials should also be maintained.

Do we use *competent* like this?

The OED gives: **Law**. *Legally qualified or sufficient*. While [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/competent) gives: *(Of a court or other body) accepted as having legal authority to deal with a particular matter*.

Maybe the concept of 'other body' can be extended to include officials?

Comment: Yes, as you have discovered *competent* has a variety of senses in which it is used; and as *one having authority* (not necessarily of a court, but any official body) is one of them.

Comment: Note that when you legally assign a court a certain authority, it means that within the context of law, that court is _legally qualified or sufficient_. The meaning is not that different; _Having authority_ only applies in a situation where that _authority_ is assigned based on a legal definition of _qualified or sufficient_.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of law, *competence* has as much to do with having jurisdiction (legal authority to decide a particular type of case, given all its particulars) over a given case or controversy as with possessing sufficient ability and objective qualifications to deal with it. *Black's Law Dictionary* (1984) offers this definition of *competent authority*:

> **COMPETENT AUTHORITY.** As applied to courts and public officers, this term imports jurisdiction and due legal authority to deal with the particular matter in question.

As you can see, this definition applies the notion of "competent authority" to both "courts" and "public officers."